# Valgrind error: Invalid write of size 8 while using lists made of struct and malloc

Tags: c, linked-list, valgrind, singly-linked-list, function-definition

I've problem with Valgrind, today it's the first day I started use it and I really not pratic with it.
Here's my code:

```
//list' typedef
typedef struct nodo_s {
    int n;
    struct nodo_s * next;
} nodo_t;


//function with error
void cambiaDirezioneSinistra(nodo_t * head)
{
    nodo_t * tmp, *temp;
    for(tmp = head; tmp != NULL; tmp = tmp->next)
        ;
    printf("1s: %d\n", tmp->n);
    temp = head;
    printf("2s: %d\n", temp->n);
    head = temp->next;
    printf("3s: %d\n", head->n);
    tmp->next = temp; ----> error
    printf("4s: %d\n", tmp->n);
    temp->next = NULL;
}


//main
int main()
{
    int i;
    int dir;
    nodo_t * head = NULL;

    for(i = 0; i < N; i ++)
        head = nuovoNodo(head);

    stampaLista(head);

    printf("Inserisci la direzione di scambio, 0 per sinistra e 1 per destra.\n");
    scanf("%d", &dir);

    if(dir == 0)
        cambiaDirezioneSinistra(head);
    else if(dir == 1)
        cambiaDirezioneDestra(head);

    stampaLista(head);

    return 0;
}
```

And here's Valgrind report of the error:

```
 ==511== Invalid write of size 8
 ==511==    at 0x10930F: cambiaDirezioneSinistra (20200120_6.c:55)
 ==511==    by 0x1094EE: main (20200120_6.c:103)
 ==511==  Address 0x8 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
 ==511== 
 ==511== 
 ==511== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
 ==511==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x8
 ==511==    at 0x10930F: cambiaDirezioneSinistra (20200120_6.c:55)
 ==511==    by 0x1094EE: main (20200120_6.c:103)
```

I've tried a lot of "solution" finded in internet, but I couldn't resolve it in any way. Thanks.

Comment: Look at the `for` loop in `cambiaDirezioneSinistra`.  It terminates only when `tmp` is NULL, so `tmp` is not a valid pointer to use after the loop.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: _Side note:_ `tmp` and `temp` aren't very descriptive of their usage. Better to use names like `cur`, `next`, `prev`, etc. Doing so might help in your understanding the `for` loop that Nate mentioned. At a guess, I'd say you're trying to find the tail of the list (e.g.) `node *tail = NULL; for (node cur = head;  cur != NULL;  cur = cur->next) tail = cur;` Note that after this, `tail` might [still] be `NULL` (i.e. the list is empty), so you'll have to check for `tail == NULL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function  `cambiaDirezioneSinistra` has undefined behavior.

For starters the pointer to the head node is passed by value. So the function deals with a copy of the value of the pointer to the head node. Changing the copy does not influence on the original pointer.

```
void cambiaDirezioneSinistra(nodo_t * head)
```

The pointer to the head node can be equal to NULL. But there is no check within the function whether `head` is equal to NULL.

After this loop

```
for(tmp = head; tmp != NULL; tmp = tmp->next)
    ;
```

the pointer `tmp` will be equal to NULL. So accessing data members of the structure using this pointer does not make sense.

The function can be declared and defined the following way

```
//function with error
void cambiaDirezioneSinistra( nodo_t **head )
{
    if ( *head != NULL && ( *head )->next != NULL )
    {
        nodo_t *last = *head;

        while ( last->next ) last = last->next;

        last->next = *head;
        *head = ( *head )->next;

        last->next->next = NULL;
    }
}
```

And the function is called like

```
cambiaDirezioneSinistra( &head );
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//list' typedef
typedef struct nodo_s 
{
    int n;
    struct nodo_s * next;
} nodo_t;


//function with error
void cambiaDirezioneSinistra( nodo_t **head )
{
    if ( *head != NULL && ( *head )->next != NULL )
    {
        nodo_t *last = *head;

        while ( last->next ) last = last->next;

        last->next = *head;
        *head = ( *head )->next;

        last->next->next = NULL;
    }
}

int append( nodo_t **head, int n )
{
    while ( *head ) head = &( *head )->next;
    
    *head = malloc( sizeof( nodo_t ) );
    int success = *head != NULL;
    
    if ( success )
    {
        ( *head )->n = n;
        ( *head )->next = NULL;
    }
    
    return success;
}

void display( const nodo_t *head )
{
    for ( ; head != NULL; head = head->next )
    {
        printf( "%d -> ", head->n );
    }
    
    puts( "null" );
}

void clear( nodo_t **head )
{
    while ( *head )
    {
        nodo_t *tmp = *head;
        *head = ( *head )->next;
        free( tmp );
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    nodo_t *head = NULL;
    
    const int N = 10;
    
    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) append( &head, i );
    
    display( head );
    
    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        cambiaDirezioneSinistra( &head );
    
        display( head );
    }
    
    clear( &head );
    
    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> null
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> 0 -> null
2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> 0 -> 1 -> null
3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> 0 -> 1 -> 2 -> null
4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> 0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> null
5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> 0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> null
6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> 0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> null
7 -> 8 -> 9 -> 0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> null
8 -> 9 -> 0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> null
9 -> 0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> null
0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> null
```

Pay attention to that if you need to access the last node of the list in functions then it is better to define the singly-linked list as a two-sided singly-linked list.

For example

```
typedef struct lista_t
{
    nodo_t *head;
    nodo_t *tail;
} lista_t;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, now I've understood my (quite stupid) errors.